# moveable circular menu in android like in screen recorders

Tags: java, android, android-studio, menu

[I want to create moveable circular menu in android like the ones used in screen recorder apps. Is there any library for it ?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WK6El.jpg)

Comment: we don't provide recommendations to libraries here, unfortunately

Comment: Not a fan of libraries myself. But i am kind of stuck here. So how about an answer then ?

Comment: Were you able to resolve this? @ user14733251 . I was able to create the circular menu but unable to add the window overlay around it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Floating Action Buttons](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/floating-action-button) (FAB) and Android [animation API](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation) to achieve this.
You could use [`PathInterpolator`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/TranslateAnimation) or [`TranslateAnimation`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/TranslateAnimation) for the moving FABs. Note: You can do the animations in a [declarative way](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource#Tween) as well, if you don't want to do it in a programmatic way.

I found a [tutorial](https://www.sitepoint.com/animating-android-floating-action-button/) which I think might help you.

But if you are after libraries then, there are a few libraries associated with expandable FAB which I have attached below. However, they don't seem to exactly achieve what you need.

https://github.com/zendesk/android-floating-action-button

https://github.com/nambicompany/expandable-fab

Note: I have never used any of those library. I'm  just giving some pointers here.

Comment: I appreciate your effort. I've already tried the above solutions but this doesn't solve my problem. Thank you though.